# how to use every item in the loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, delay

I'm created a new script with php. I manipulate the picture uploaded by the user with 40 different models and show them in the page.

The user has to wait until all 40 pictures are prepared with my current code.

```
$file = $this->post['uploaded_image'];

$models = $this->post['models'];
/*
User selected models, etc:
['model-1', 'model-2', 'model-8', 'model-14', 'model-22', 'model-34', 'model-35', 'model-40']
*/

foreach ($models as $model) {
    $resize_image = $this->resize($file, $model);
    $final_image = $this->crop($resize_image, $model, $file);
    return $final_image;
}
```

I want to do is to use each image that return from the loop in order. While I use the first image and the loop continues to render in the 2nd, 3rd...

I hope I explained my problem correctly. How can I solve this problem with php or javascript?

Comment: You should take a look what [`return`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) actually does.

Comment: Can't you queue them separately? If you make multiple ajax requests, they work asynchronously anyway. So, each would render it's respective image when it's done from the server.

Comment: Also as Teemu said, remove the `return` from your loop.

Comment: I use this function in my class. What can I use except for return?

Comment: @MimRa `return` returns value before the loop finishes.

Comment: Have you read, what a yield function can do for you? PHP yields do not mess with memory consumption and are very comfortable. Beside that you should see, that PHP runs on the server and the view normally appears on the client side. So it 's pretty normal, that the foreach loop has to finish, until it shows up in the view. Other techniques could be the JavaScript APIs like the FileReader API.